# Android, always pop complete action using

Tags: android, android-intent

I write a button to lanuch media player,
if user have 2 media player, it will pop "complete action using" dialog
but when I clicked the use by default for this action, and select the media player, 
next time I start my app and click the button it will ask again.
Please help me how to fix the problem

when user click button ,it will do follow

```
try
{
    musicIntent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
startActivity(musicIntent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

thank you very much

Comment: this is functionality of android itself.. if you want to open mp3 in specific application. than set classname of that app in intent..

Comment: Thank you Sanket Kachhela, but we don't know user have what mp3 player,so we make the button let user select

Comment: than go ahed with your current code...

Answer (score 0):

I find when I use

```
musicIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
musicIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
startActivityForResult(musicIntent, PLAY_MUSIC);
```

this problem will fix,but I don't know why...

thanks everyone

Answer (score -1):

If you use CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC the operation will handled by the system. If you want to use something specific then you need to specify it yourself with its classname.

Comment: please use suggestions as a comment not as answer